# get the sum between the difference of numbers in an array in JAVA

Tags: java, arrays

I have an array where I put the quantity of numbers I want, it could be 5, it could be 100 numbers, and I have a method that calculates de difference between two numbers.

What I want to develop is a method that goes to the array and using the `getDifference` method calculates the diference between the 1st and 2nd number, the 2nd number and the 3rd number, the 3rd number and the 4 number and so on until reaches the end of the array and then returns the sum of all that diferences. Any ideas?

```
int[] myIntArray = new int[x numbers];

public int getDifference(int num1, int num2) {
    return num2-num1;    
}

public int getSumDifference(int[] numbers) {
    ...
}
```

I know this method is wrong, its just to make my point of view.

Comment: I don't understand why you have a method called `getDiference` (which is misspelled), when you can simply use the `-` operator to get the difference of two numbers without involving the inefficiency of calling a method.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The proper approach, IMHO, is to use basic math to reduce this problem. For an array of size N, you'd want to calculate:

```
S = (a[1] - a[2]) + (a[2] - a[3]) + ... + (a[N-1] - a[N])
```

So, if you open the brackets and reduce the problem, you'd get:

```
S = a[1] - a[N]
```

Representing this in Java should be easy enough:

```
public int getSumDiference(int[] numbers){
    return numbers[0] - numbers[numbers.length - 1];
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Lets say your list has 4 values: `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`.
So differences are `a - b`, `b - c`, `c - d`.
Sum of those are `(a - b) + (b - c) + (c - d)`.
Removing parenthesis gets you `a - b + b - c + c - d`.
Since `-b + b` is nothing, we get `a - d`.

Result: **First value minus last value**.

Just skip all the intermediate calculations, they are a waste of time.